# Would you consider this a left outer join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SELECT * FROM LOCN_HDR LH, PICK_LOCN_DTL PLD WHERE pld.locn_id = lh.locn_id(+)
```

I'm attempting to convert some older code written for oracle, to be able to run it on SQL SERVER. I've not used the (+) before but from a quick google i'm led to believe it's an outer join, and when it's sat on the right, it's a left join, so bring back everything from locn_hdr plus whatever matches from pick_locn_dtl. Is that right?

Only when I test this, it doesn't appear to be working as I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `(+)` is on the right side of the join expression, it is a left join on the table on the left of the *expression* (i.e. equal to `pld LEFT JOIN lh`), so it will bring back every row from `pld` (i.e. `PICK_LOCN_DTL`) matched with equivalent rows from `lh` (`LOCN_HDR`).

The left/right connotation applies to the left/right of the expression that has the `(+)` itself, not to the order of tables in the `FROM` clause.

This would give an ANSI standard join syntax of

```
SELECT *
  FROM pick_locn_dtl PLD
     LEFT JOIN locn_hdr LH
        ON pld.locn_id = lh.locn_id
```

Comment: @BriteSponge - thanks for the edit and adding in the equivalent ANSI-compatible SQL!

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle the (+) is OUTER JOIN, here is a good link where it explains the difference

```
https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
```